# Optimization of Google App Engine Code

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine is yelling at me about the high amount of quota that this code is using.

What can I do to make it less heavy?

```
public  void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse  resp)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

             PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
             HttpSession session = req.getSession();

             if(session.isNew()){
                 session.invalidate();
                 resp.sendRedirect("/login.html");
             }

             else {

             User usr22 = (User) session.getAttribute("username");


             String query = "select from veep.User where email == '"+ usr22.getEmail() +"'";

         List<User> users = (List<User>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();

            User usr = users.get(0);

               System.out.println("estou no SERVMVCCCCC!!" + usr);

           List<String> discsNAct = usr.getDisciplinasNAct();
           List<String> discsActs = usr.getDisciplinasAct();


                req.setAttribute("nact", discsNAct);
                req.setAttribute("act", discsActs);
                req.setAttribute("discs", discsNAct);

            session.invalidate();
            session = req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", usr);
            session.setAttribute("loggedIn", new String("true"));

                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/conta_d.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(req, resp);              


                try {
                    pm.makePersistent(usr);
                } finally {
                    pm.close();
                }
             }
        }
```

Comment: We don't have the code for `usr.getDisciplinasNAct()` and `usr.getDisciplinasAct` so it's hard to get an idea of the CPU usage. Also why get the session, invalidate it and get it again?

Comment: the getDisciplinas* is just a simple return List<String>. I want to block access to the "else" code to users with a valid session. I tried session == null and it didn't work so I did it that way.

Comment: Have you tried installing AppStats?  Often AppStats will show you which lines of your code are (unexpectedly) making a ton of RPC calls to the datastore. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html